# iPad Split View "Zoom Down" Table View

Tags: ios, uitableview, ipad

I am trying to get a good idea of a good way to add items to a split view for iPad. My idea was where you tap the plus button and the table view scrolls down (quickly) to below the table that is there to a screen where you can enter in the new stuff. Then when you click done it zooms back up to the main table.

Is this possible and/or what is a better way to do a addition for a split view with a table to the left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the point of using a split view is to flatten the heirarchy of doing things with a table view (basically), so why not when you hit the add button, have a view come up in the detail view (the right hand side) with fields to edit and etc? Or use a popover controller to display the 'add cell' view.

Comment: Hey, this is good, but what do you mean by popover controller?